# использование операторов +=, = Java

Tags: java

Почему в строке 1 возникает ошибка компиляции, а в строке 2 нет?

```
public class text {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b1 = 127;
    b1 = b1 + 1; // 1
    b1 += 1;     // 2
  }
}
```

Comment: b1 = b1 + 1 здесь, в правой части, происходит выполнение действий в формате int числа. Во втором случае вы вызываете оператор +=, который работает с арифметикой левого аргумента (в вашем случае byte). Вообще, для целых чисел, любые операции +,-,*,/ в первую очередь ведут себя именно как int. А уже по вашему желанию, можете сделать что то вроде b1 = (byte)(b1 + 1), что исправит ошибку.

Comment: т.е. сокращенные операции типа += работают с арифметикой левого операнда и являются допустимыми, верно?

Comment: Это отдельный оператор. В данном случае, он ведёт себя эквивалентно a+=1 <=> a=a+1. В других языках он может быть перегружен и вести себя как угодно. Да, всё верно.

Answer (score 11):

Для сложения в JVM есть 4 опкода - iadd, ladd, fadd и dadd. Для типов integer, long, float и double, соответственно. Поэтому сложение двух байт будет скомпилировано в

```
iload_1
iload_2
iadd
istore_3
```

То есть операнды будут загружены в стек как integer'ы и результат сложения вернётся в виде integer. А попытка сохранить integer в byte без явного преобразования может привести к переполнению. О чём предупреждает компилятор.

Это поведение зафиксировано в [JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

Операция `b1 += 1;` будет скомпилирована в

```
iload_1
iconst_1
iadd
i2b
istore_1
```

Интересен здесь опкод i2b - преобразование из integer в byte. То есть компилятор делает неявное приведение типов.

А это поведение зафиксировано в [JLS 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 4):

См. документацию [Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Здесь вывод 'b1 += 1' интерпретируется в 'b1 = (byte) b1 + 1'