# Почему вылезает ошибка несовместимости типов?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, типы, byte

Почему выдается ошибка "Error: java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte" в языке Java при компиляции следующего кода:

```
byte b;
byte b1 = 1;
byte b2 = 2;
b = b1 + b2;
```

тип переменной b - byte, типы переменных b1 и b2 тоже byte. Почему несовместимость?

Comment: А вы мысленно замените в этом коде `b2 = 2` на `b2 = 127`.

Comment: Потому что операция `+` интовая

Comment: Все упрощенные операторы приводят результат к типу переменной. https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yYNRDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82+%2B%3D+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+byte&source=bl&ots=TaCkmG_qxV&sig=ACfU3U0wJbeVLpFtv_ARBcdhKOA60guxoA&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi14Ira5bHpAhUrx4sKHaicAYwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%2B%3D%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20byte&f=false

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець а почему операция "+" интовая? Ведь если мы сложим int и long, то полученный тип будет long.

Comment: @ВерховаГалина тут выше сцылко на книгу, там все о преобразованиях типов - сужающих, расширяющих...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [использование операторов +=, = Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/847687/204271)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [использование операторов +=, = Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847687/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно кастить

```
byte b;
byte b1 = 1;
byte b2 = 2;
b = (byte) (b1 + b2);
```

Вот [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/types.php) кстати, объясняется почему так происходит